# Getting Max Value Of A Point On DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0, datagrid

I have a datagrid where a user will input heights in inches then feet and I want to capture the tallest people (based off feet only).  I have tried the below syntax, but I get a compile error of:

> Non invocable member 'DataGridViewRow.Cells can not be used like a method

This is my syntax - what would be the appropriate way to get the max value of column 1 in my datagrid?

```
double MaxVal = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in HeightGrid.Rows)
{
    if (row.Cells(1).Value > MaxVal)
    {
        MaxVal = row.Cells(1).Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the max:

```
MaxVal = dataGridView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                    .Max(r => Convert.ToDouble(r.Cells[1].Value));
```

where `Cells[1]` denotes the second column.

To your second query:

```
var biggestRow = dataGridView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                    .Aggregate((r1,r2) => Convert.ToDouble(r1.Cells[1].Value) > Convert.ToDouble(r2.Cells[1].Value) ? r1 : r2);
```

This should give you the row with the biggest value in your second column. From there, you can extract the first and second cells.

Comment: I am actually after the second column, so I altered it to r.Cells[1] but when I try to run, I get an error of System.FOrmatException occurined in mscorlib.dll  I am inputting values with decimals if that makes a diff so like 10001.23

Comment: Sorry, that should have been a conversion to a double. Try the updated code.

Comment: Yes, the convert to double did it.  How can I also read the value from position r.Cells[0] that corresponds to the MaxVal?

Comment: That's a separate question from the one stated in the OP, and different requirements change how you approach a problem. For example, perhaps you should retrieve the entire row that has the maximum value in the 2nd column? What other requirements are you going to add after you get r.Cells[0]?

Comment: My apalogy @C. Helling - that is all I am after is to retrieve both r.Cells[0] and r.Cells[1] where MaxVal = r.Cells[1]

Comment: Couple ways to do it. Run a second query (inefficient), like `var rows = dataGridView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(r => r.Cells[1].Equals(MaxVal))` which will give you all rows that have that max value (and from there, you can look at index 0 or 1 of that row). Another way is to use the MaxBy function in the MoreLinq project: code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/…. A 3rd way would be to use Aggregate(), which I will edit into my post as a way to try.

Comment: @C.Helling - for me this returns the row number, how do I actually return the data that is in the rows?

Comment: @BellHopByDayAmetuerCoderByNigh Sorry, could you clairfy your question? Which query are you using? What data is in your cells?

Comment: @C.Helling - I am utulizing your var biggest row example.  My values are float values, but a row number is returned such as dataGridViewRow { Index=3 }  --- I would like to see the actual values returned, or a way to parse them from the response.

Comment: @BellHopByDayAmetuerCoderByNigh Are you sure it's a row number being returned instead of a `DataGridViewRow` object? If you hover over `biggestRow` in debug, what type of class is it? Can you access `biggestRow.Cells[0]` etc in the Watch?

Comment: @C.Helling - if i access biggestRow.Cells[0]; in watch The value is DataGridViewTextBoxCell {ColumnIndex=0, RowIndex-1 and the Type is System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell {System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxCell } --- does that answer your ?

Comment: @C.Helling - it appears that biggestRow.Cells[1].Value and biggestRow.Cells[0].Value hold the actual values that were input.  The Value Type is Name= "Object" FullName = "System.Object"

Comment: @BellHopByDayAmetuerCoderByNigh Okay, so can you verify what type `biggestRow` is? It sounds like it is indeed a `DataGridViewRow` and that you should be able to extract the values in your row.

Comment: Without being able to see your data, it's hard to verify exactly what should be in it. You can try adding a `.ToString()` to `biggestRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString()` to perhaps see what's inside.

Comment: @C.Helling - yes that is how I can extract!  Thank you for th assistance (and I learned how to use the watch window!)

Comment: @BellHopByDayAmetuerCoderByNigh haha, glad to hear you got to learn something new. Hopefully should help your debugging in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It means that Cells is a *property*, not a *method*, and as such should be accessed as DataGridViewRow.Cells, not DataGridViewRow.Cells().

Comment: But I want to access index 1 of the DataGridView - how can I specify such?